# How can I turn a $0^0$ form into a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ form?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I am trying to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}(x-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{\log x}}$$

It's a $0^0$ intedeterminate form, and I am unsure how to deal with it. I have a feeling that if I could turn it to a form where L'Hopital's rule is applicable, then I'd have a chance at solving the problem.

Is there any consistent way of turning a $0^0$ form into a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ form?

If not, how do you deal with this kind of limits?

Comment: $\log0^0=0\cdot\infty=\frac1\infty\cdot\infty=0\cdot\frac10$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general trick is to apply exponential/logarithm to the expression:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} (x - \sin{x})^{\frac{1}{\log{x}}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\frac{\log(x - \sin{x})}{\log{x}}} = e^{\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(x - \sin{x})}{\log{x}}}
$$
Now you can apply L'Hopital Rule to the limit in the exponent. I use $=_L$ to denote equality when L'Hopital Rule is applied.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(x - \sin{x})}{\log{x}} &=_L \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1 - \cos{x}}{x - \sin{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x - x\cos{x}}{x - \sin{x}} \\
&=_L \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1 - \cos{x} + x\sin{x}}{1 - \cos{x}} \\
&=_L \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{2\sin{x} + x\cos{x}}{\sin{x}} \\
&=_L \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{3\cos{x} - x\sin{x}}{\cos{x}} \\
&= \frac{3 - 0}{1} \\
&= 3
\end{align*}
Thus the desired limit is $e^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting into an indeterminant product using exponentiation by $e$:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (x - \sin x)^{\frac{1}{\log x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\ln(x - \sin x)(\frac{1}{\log x})}$$ and you can go from here using L'Hopital

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}(x-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$$
$$^\lim_{x\to0^{+}}e^{\ln(x-\sin x)^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}}$$

$$e^{\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\ln(x-\sin x)}{\ln(x)}}$$

Applying L Hospital as we have $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ form

$$e^{\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{x(1-\cos x)}{x-\sin x}}=1$$

$$e^{\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{x^3(1-\cos x)}{x^2(x-\sin x)}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\dfrac{1}{6}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

After putting these values , you will get final answer as $e^3$

Comment: The correct answer is $e^3$

Comment: ok I think I made a mistake in differentation, I think you have got  idea about how to approach, I will just corrrect it

Comment: Yes, I definitely got the point, thank you

Comment: I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to take logs. If $L$ is the desired limit then we have $$\log L=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\log(x-\sin x)} {\log x} $$ The expression under limit above can be rewritten as $$3+\dfrac{\log\dfrac{x-\sin x} {x^3}} {\log x} $$ and the numerator here tends to $\log(1/6)$ and denominator tends to $-\infty $ so that the fraction tends to $0$. It follows that $L=e^3$. The limit $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{x-\sin x} {x^3}=\frac{1}{6}$$ is easily handled by L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series.